# Help with understanding congruence of curves

Tags: calculus-of-variations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

[Document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0210140.pdf) page: 10 of pdf\page number 9

I am not undertanding this part:

> Then the elementary existence theorem for solutions of first
> order ordinary differential equations implies that eq. 2.17 defines an n-parameter
> family of curves in the region $G$, such that each point in $G$ has a unique curve pass
> through it

Suppose I have a solution $x = \alpha t + \beta t^2$,(a 2-parameter family of curves) then the point $(x,y,t) = (0,0,0)$ does not have a unique curve as both this curve: $x = t + t^2$ and this curve: $x = 2t + 2t^2$ go through the point $(0,0,0)$

It is obvious that I am not understanding some thing here (this whole *congruence of curves* part is a bit confusing) and would really appreciate any help you can provide. Also if possible an example.